# git push heroku master error: cannot spawn ssh: No such file or directory fatal: unable to fork

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
git push heroku master
 error: cannot spawn ssh: No such file or directory fatal:
 unable to fork
```

I have windows 8 and i am working on the third rails tutorial. When I use the railsinstaller I push my app through Heroku. For the tutorial I had to make some changes and add extra gems and now I do not have access to Heroku.
Heroku has my key. I checked it.
Thank you for helping

Comment: This error means that git can't find your ssh executable or launch it.  Are you using git bash?  How'd you install git?

Answer (score 0):

Try running "ssh -T git@github.com" in your terminal to see if you're authenticated. I suggest following this guide if you haven't already done so: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys